# Es posible actualizar una tabla con OPENQUERY?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, plsql

Realicé una conexión entre una BD de remota de MySQL con una BD local en SQL-Server, el tema es que las opciones de *OpenQuery*, al parecer, solo deja actualizar datos fila por fila. ¿Es posible actualizar una columna completa usando id para actualizar una tabla de MySQL en SQL-Server?

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY (OracleSvr, 'SELECT name FROM joe.titles WHERE id = 
101')   
SET name = 'ADifferentName';
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. La redacción de la pregunta no me parece clara. Te invito a leer [ask] y luego [edit] tu pregunta y tratar de explicarte mejor, bien con otras palabras, o quizás con un pequeño ejemplo. Un saludo.

Comment: Otro punto que me genera algo de confusión es que mencionas MySQL, pero tu _linked server_ se llama `OracleSvr`. Hablamos de MySQL o de Oracle?